# MySQL error 1054 - unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql

Whenever I try to insert a new row or change the value of the "nume" field in tip3 table I get this error:

[image: sql_error_1054]

Also this is my table structure:

[image: tip3 structure]

And the sql query:

```
CREATE TABLE `tip3` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_tip2` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `nume` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_tip2` (`id_tip2`, `nume`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=47
;
```

I used the same structure and query for another table and there it works.

Comment: Show us the query you ran, and also update with the database you used.  HeidiSQL just sits on top of another database, so a query is still DB-dependent.

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` shown will not create the error message from the screenshot

Comment: maybe there is a Trigger in your DB?

Comment: Thanks Jens. It was a trigger after all with a little syntax error which I fixed it.